# Content of whole page is still present even after the pdf file is cropped

Tags: python, pdfbox, pdftotext

I cropped a pdf file with the help of pypdf2 but when i try to extract text from that cropped pdf file, Im getting the text of whole pdf page. How can I resolve that?

After cropping pdf file look like is[image]

But when I run command `pdftotext out8.pdf out.txt`

I get :

Contents
Introduction
Part I. Two Systems

1. The Characters of the Story
2. Attention and Effort
3. The Lazy Controller
4. The Associative Machine
5. Cognitive Ease
6. Norms, Surprises, and Causes
7. A Machine for Jumping to Conclusions
8. How Judgments Happen
9. Answering an Easier Question
   Part II. Heuristics and Biases
10. The Law of Small Numbers
    <5>
11. Anchors
12. The Science of Availability
13. Availability, Emotion, and Risk
14. Tom W’s Specialty

The output was supposed to be only

1. The Characters of the Story

The code I ran

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader
input1 = PdfFileReader(open("./data/in2.pdf", "rb"))
output = PdfFileWriter()

page = input1.getPage(1)
x = page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_x()
y = page.mediaBox.getUpperRight_y()

page.cropBox.lowerRight = (0,331-150)
page.cropBox.upperRight = (252,331)
output.addPage(page)

outputStream = open("out8.pdf", "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Comment: Thanos one of my most favorite Villians of all times.  My favorite quote by him was in Thanos Quest Book 2. "Who would have thought that becoming God would be such a hollow victory."

Comment: @Scott Boston Ah you came back so much :) I love Thanos too. Im a huge fan of marvel. Waiting for infinity war.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it is extracting the text from the text layer. PDFs can have more than one layer - if it is purely an image PDF, then it will just have the image layer but many have an image layer with a text layer. The text layer can be in front of the image, behind the image or not visible.

Unless the PDF has been prepared in a special way, the text layer does not align with the text seen in the image. If you have a multipage PDF, then the text may be split into the relevant pages but otherwise not arranged across the page.

When you crop the image, this does not affect the text layer. When you extract the text, this grabs it from the text layer which is intact.

In order to get just the text of the cropped section, you'll need to process it through an OCR engine e.g Tesseract. Examples of python packages which interface with Tesseract: [pytesseract](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytesseract) and [tesserocr](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tesserocr).

Some guides on how to set it up and run the processing:

[ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python](https://pythontips.com/2016/02/25/ocr-on-pdf-files-using-python/)
[ocr-python-easy](http://www.manejandodatos.es/2014/11/ocr-python-easy/)

Comment: Ocr takes a lot of time for processing. Is there any way for very fast processing?

Comment: No. PDF is designed as a page-level viewing document, not something for processing. Tesseract is quick for an ocr engine, although if you're doing a hundreds of pages then as you say it will take some time. Example timings: 1 page solid text = 2.5 seconds, full book 305 pages mostly solid text = 13 minutes. To speed things up, you might want to change you approach; is there any way you can use a different source? E.g. regex on the text, or if it's a webpage, use beautiful soup to scrape the parts of the page you want. Otherwise, you're stuck with ocr.